# How can I copy my class unlocks between computers?

Tags: hack-slash-loot

I played [Hack Slash Loot](http://hackslashloot.com/) for a few hours on one computer (Windows version) and unlocked the Knight class. The Windows version of the game consists of a single .exe file and I didn't see any other files created in the folder I'd unzipped it to which might hold the player data, nor did I find it under "My Documents" or any of its subdirectories.

Where can I find the player data so that I can copy my progress to another computer?

Comment: Sometimes it's unavoidable, but I usually play different games (e.g. not both Hack Slash Loot) on different computers to avoid this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The developer ended up responding to me on his forums:

### Windows

%APPDATA%/HackSlashLoot/Data/  (For me, "%APPDATA%" was *C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming*)

### Mac

~/Library/Application Support/HackSlashLoot/Data/

### Linux

~/.HackSlashLoot/Data/

Furthermore, it seems that class unlocks are tied entirely to the number of player deaths. Die a lot, and more classes will unlock. If you don't have access to the computer you were originally playing on and wish to unlock the classes (or if you just want to unlock them all early, since "dying a lot" really isn't any measure of skill) simply edit the number of "TotalDeaths" in the settings.xml file to be a large number.

Comment: Very helpful -- I was able to move the folder to my Google Drive, and place a symbolic link in it's place, so now it will sync between machines automatically.  (Would have been simpler if the dev. had just used Windows' built-in "Saved Games" folder, but this works too.)